# display a range of numbers with a slider in streamlit

Tags: python, dataframe, slider, streamlit

I'm putting some Horse Racing data into streamlit and have used filters with smaller options like `"Select Country"` - This will give me the option to filter out United Kingdom or Ireland. The code I've used is:

```
Country = st.sidebar.multiselect(
    "Select a Country",
    options=df["Country"].unique(),
    default=df["Country"].unique()
) 

if_selection = df.query(
    "Country == @Country"
)
```

This works fine.

I would like to add a slider that will display horses within a particular rating on a slider.
Something like display horses with a rating of 200 - 250 or 100-275.

I have used the following code:

```
RDB_Rating =st.slider("Please select a rating range",
                      0, 300,)
st.write("RDB_Rating: ", RDB_Rating)
```

This has displayed the slider, but I can't figure out how to assign it to the RDB_Rating column in the df to filter out the horses I am interested in.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you will need to provide two values to the slider's default values ([see docs on `value` argument for reference](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/widgets/st.slider)):

```
rdb_rating = st.slider("Please select a rating range",
                       min_value=0,
                       max_value=300,
                       value=(200, 250))
```

`rdb_rating` now has a tuple of (low, high) and you can just filter your DataFrame using simple boolean indexing or [`Series.between`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html). Here's an example:

```
df[df['Rating'].between(*rdb_rating, inclusive='both')]
# or 
df[df.query("Rating >= rdb_rating[0] and Rating <= rdb_rating[1]")]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way :

```
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Horse": ["Horse 1", "Horse 2", "Horse 3", "Horse 4", "Horse 5"],
    "RDB_Rating": [230, 186, 255, 450, 171],
    "Country": ["UK", "Colombia", "Egypt", "Brazil", "Japan"]}
)

Country = st.sidebar.multiselect(
    "Select a Country",
    options=df["Country"].unique(),
    default=df["Country"].unique()
)

RDB_Rating = st.sidebar.slider("Select a rating range", 0, 300, (0, 300))

if Country:
    df = df[df["Country"].isin(Country)]

if RDB_Rating:
    df = df[df["RDB_Rating"].between(RDB_Rating[0], RDB_Rating[1])]

st.write(df)
```

Output :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To filter your `DataFrame` based on the `RDB_Rating slider` value, you can modify your `if_selection` statement to include an additional condition based on the `RDB_Rating` value, like this:

```
RDB_Rating = st.slider("Please select a rating range", 0, 300)
if_selection = df.query("Country == @Country and @RDB_Rating_min <= RDB_Rating <= @RDB_Rating_max",RDB_Rating_min=RDB_Rating[0],RDB_Rating_max=RDB_Rating[1])
```

*Make sure to include the above code after defining the `Country` variable and before displaying the filtered `DataFrame`.*